# player naming with loops

Tags: java, loops

Im having a problem with a loop im doing. When ever I run the program it displays

Please enter the name of player 1?

Please enter the name of player 2?

When I enter the first name it automatically prints please enter the name of player three. three players have been created but I can only name 2 it appears
Any advice

```
   public static void startGame()
    {
    System.out.println("How many players would you like?");
    int noPlayers = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < noPlayers; i++)
    {

        System.out.println("What is the 1st name of Player " + (i + 1) + "?" );  
        String name = input.nextLine();
        Player player = new Player (name, 80);
        players.add(player);

    }
```

note that the 80 is money.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint/1310206

Answer (score 0):

You should add `input.nextLine()` after `int noPlayers = input.nextInt();`, to consume the end of the line in which the number of players was entered.

```
   public static void startGame()
   {
       System.out.println("How many players would you like?");
       int noPlayers = input.nextInt();
       input.nextLine(); // add this
       for (int i = 0; i < noPlayers; i++)
       {
           System.out.println("What is the 1st name of Player " + (i + 1) + "?" );  
           String name = input.nextLine();
           Player player = new Player (name, 80);
           players.add(player);  
       }
   }
```